# Return bad request (400) for missing required parameter

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

```
[HttpPost("test")]
public IActionResult Teste(int? id)
{
    if (!id.HasValue)
        return BadRequest();

    ...
}
```

How can i return badrequest without use 'int?' if client doesn't send id?

There is some simple way to return badrequest automatically in this case?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What is the problem. The code in the question should perform what you are asking about.

Comment: Because if i use 'int', if client doesnt send id, id will be 0 and this is a problem for me.There is some simple way to return badrequest automatically when client doesn't send some parameter?

Comment: Make the parameter optional `int? id = null`

Comment: 'int? id' are null even without using '=null' when client doesnt send 'id'.

Comment: yes. Try it and see if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just put the id in the path like such:

```
[HttpPost("test/{id}")]
public IActionResult Teste(int id)
{
    if (id == default(int))
        return BadRequest();

    ...
}
```

You can still make sure the id is not 0 (or a more intricate validation) if you want.
This will not yield a 400 Bad Request response but I would say it's the most proper way to do it. Unless you want to have the user pass in the id in the request body, then you could do e.g. attribute validations and check the ModelState to return bad request.

Comment: I'm trying to skip extra validations. This 'if' will need to be added not just to every controller, but to every action on that controller.

Comment: But if you just omit the if statement you should be good to go. This will force the client to always pass in an id (in the path). It's another case if the client actively chooses to pass in an invalid id, such as 0, but I don't see how you could go around validating that...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to automatically send a 400 in the case of an invalid parameter but, as a quick workaround, you could do something like this:

```
public IActionResult Teste(int id = -1)
```

Setting a default value, you can easily identify an invalid parameter and return a 400 or do whatever you like.

Also, this eliminates the ambiguity of an input with a value of 0 that you mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

You can make the parameter optional  have a default value like this

```
[HttpPost("test")]
public IActionResult Teste(int id=0)
{
    if (id==0)
        return BadRequest();

    ...
}
```